# Using jQuery tokeninput from loopj.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp, tokenize

I am able to select multiple options that I send from my .jsp file in JSON format. However, when I want to SUBMIT/access the values from the text input element "tokenize", I get a undefined output. I am a novice to java script and so what to touch and what not to touch.

Q: Could someone provide/point me to some detail on how to achieve this at the earliest??
   Is there something missing below?

Thnx in Advance,
Aditya

**Note:** The body tag got split into a separate code block. Pls donot get confused.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>  
<script>  
    google.load("jquery", "1");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/token-input.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />

    <style>
        input {
            font-size: 120%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showList()
        {
            t = document.getElementById('tokenize').valueOf();
            alert(t); //DISPLAYS 'undefined' <- LOOK HERE
        }
    </script>
```

```
<h1>Jquery Tokenizing Autocomplete Input</h1>

<form name="myForm">
    <div>
        <h2>List style</h2>
        <input type="text" id="tokenize" name="blah"/> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Parse" onClick="showList()"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Facebook style</h2>
        <input type="text" id="tokenize2" name="blah2" />
    </div>
</form>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#country").autocomplete("getData.jsp",
     {'multiple': true, 'multipleSeparator': ','});
</script> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tokenize").tokenInput("getData.jsp", {
        hintText: "Type in the names of your favorite TV shows",
        noResultsText: "No results",
        searchingText: "Searching..."
    });

    $("#tokenize2").tokenInput("getData.jsp", {
        classes: {
            tokenList: "token-input-list-facebook",
            token: "token-input-token-facebook",
            tokenDelete: "token-input-delete-token-facebook",
            selectedToken: "token-input-selected-token-facebook",
            highlightedToken: "token-input-highlighted-token-facebook",
            dropdown: "token-input-dropdown-facebook",
            dropdownItem: "token-input-dropdown-item-facebook",
            dropdownItem2: "token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook",
            selectedDropdownItem: "token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook",
            inputToken: "token-input-input-token-facebook"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showList()
    {
        //INSTEAD OF: t = document.getElementById('tokenize').valueOf();
        var t = $('#tokenize').val();
        alert(t);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah! Thanks lukiffer! I was now able to do it. Two things required are: 1. Need to replace GET with a POST in the .js file included. 2. Yes, use ".val()". You get the answer. Thanks again!!

Comment: Not to be trolling for rep points, but could you use the checkbox (left) to mark as the answer if it was helpful in resolving your issue? Cheers mate!

Comment: @lukiffer, may I ask u to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141176/facebook-style-jquery-tokeninput-script-retains-value-in-the-jquery-ui-modal-win? just expecting u to contribute there in a question about tokeninput. n i donno whether such a request is acceptable in SOF

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
var t = document.getElementById('tokenize').valueOf()
```

use

```
var t = document.getElementById('tokenize').value;
```