# facebook style jquery tokeninput script retains value in the jquery-ui modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to use facebook style [tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) script which I'll use in the same way as FB uses(using [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com) to get the modal window) to send messages to friends in a social networking system.

Clicking on the 'open the dialog' button ('opener' id makes the modal window appear)

javascript snippet:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
            alert("Would submit: " + $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val());
        });
    });

</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {



             $(".show_dialog script").remove();
         $dialog = $('.show_dialog');


         $dialog.dialog({
                width:500,
                height:300,
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Basic Dialog'
            });

        $('#opener').click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val('this is a value ')// ADDED BY ME 


            //$("#demo-input-facebook-theme", $dialog).val('');





            $(".border_text", $dialog).css("border","1px solid red");
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

html snippet is :

```
<button id="opener">Open the dialog</button>


<div class="show_dialog" style="display:block ;">


               <label class="send_meg_recipient_txt">To:</label>







<h2 id="theme">Facebook Theme</h2>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="demo-input-facebook-theme" name="blah2" " /><br></br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />


        <script type="text/javascript">
        var script = jQuery('<script/>').attr('src', 'js/jquery.tokeninput.js').appendTo('head');

        $(document).ready(function() {


        var script = jQuery('<script/>').attr('src', 'js/jquery.tokeninput.js').appendTo('head');


        var q_string=$("#demo-input-facebook-theme").val();





            $("#demo-input-facebook-theme",$dialog).tokenInput("token_find/my3.php?q=q_string", {

                preventDuplicates: true,
                theme:"facebook"

            });


        /*
        */  

        });


        </script>


    </div>


 </div><!--end of class  show_dialog-->
```

I can get the tokenizing from the script.
But after tokenizing for once if i click on the 'opener' id, the modal window appears with its previous tokens retained in place, which I obviously don't want.

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're loading the `jquery.tokeninput.js` file twice - you shouldn't need it in `$(document).ready(...)` so long as it comes after jQuery.

Once you've displayed your modal (called `$dialog.dialog('open');`) try, calling:

`$('#demo-input-facebook-theme').tokenInput("clear");`

That should clear all of the previous tokens, then you can add any default tokens you want after that.

Comment: yes, did that. tokens cleared. But the prob now is after i close the dialog box, the hinttext(i.e. Type in a search term appears on the flat web page, not on the modal  window) If I click on that text on the flat web page, and then launch the modal window again , not hint text appears on the modal window and typing any text in the input box makes nothing to appear. Should I post it as a different question in SOF?

Comment: Depending on the modal plugin you're using, you might have to check if token-input is already initialized for that selector. Sometimes the modal clones the dom elements and disposes of them when it closes rather than tracking state. So the target may be being disposed and re-cloned when the modal is displayed.

Comment: I used 'autoOpen: false' for   the modal window. when I launch the modal window except for the first time, the tokeninput plugin is applied obviously on the same selector. 1) If the plugin were initialized beforhand, won't it go through the same functionalities, it had to at the first time? 2) How to determine whether it was initialized b4 or not? 3) in whatever situation, which code should I change?

Comment: 1) In theory yes, except most lightboxes clone the DOM elements so any jQuery plugins you have may be targeting those elements which are disposed when the lightbox closes - you'll need to reinitialize the plugin on each load. 2) This varies for each plugin - tokeninput has good API documentation. 3) I would suggest initializing the plugin targeting the same selector on each load of the lightbox.

Comment: trying to understand. selector.pluginname() - is this initialization ? can u shed a bit more light on reinitialization?

Comment: Please share which lightbox/modal you're using and I'll throw an example together to explain.

Comment: let me see the fiddle . May I request you to have a visit at a different question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554666/type-show-a-name-list-like-facebook-status-box?